# scapy - Name Error "global name 'Padding' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-2.6, scapy

Im trying to write little http proxy server just for testing how scapy handles packet with `StreamSocket`.

```
from scapy.all import *
import socket

sk = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print "Start"
sk.bind(("127.0.0.1",8090))
sk.listen(1)
conn , addr = sk.accept()
ss = StreamSocket(conn)
r = ss.recv(2048)
print r
ss.close()
```

When I got the line `r = ss.recv(2048)` it says (on scapy 2.2.0):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 254, in run_nodebug
File "C:\Python26\ProxyServer\module1.py", line 21, in <module>
    r = ss.recv()
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\supersocket.py", line 126, in recv
    pad = pkt.getlayer(Padding)
NameError: global name 'Padding' is not defined
```

I have tried to update my scapy (from 2.2.0 to 2.3.2) and it does the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 254, in run_nodebug
File "C:\Python26\ProxyServer\module1.py", line 21, in <module>
    r = ss.recv()
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\supersocket.py", line 126, in recv
    pkt = self.basecls(pkt)
NameError: global name 'Padding' is not defined
```

Please Help?
sorry for my bad english

Note: I have windows 7 64 bit , python 2.6 and now scapy 2.3.2

Comment: Is the second traceback exactly what you are getting? Because there is no `Padding` on line 126 in scapy 2.3.2. How did you update? I guess there are some leftovers from earlier versions. Perhaps uninstalling and reinstalling scapy helps.

Comment: I dont want to sound stupid but I removed scapy 2.2.0 manualy (by removing the site-packages/scapy and the Scripts/scapy)
There is a way to do it automaticly ? like `python setup.py uninstall` or something like that ?

Comment: Maybe there are some (hidden) files left? Is the second traceback exactly what you are getting?

Comment: The second traceback its exactly what Im getting I Copy-Paste it

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure that there are some *.pyc files of the old scapy somewhere that are being used instead of the new *.py files. Search for supersocket.pyc on C:

Comment: I found 1 but it last modified today (then i guess it from 2.3.2)
But anyway I want try your idea (uninstalling all scapy and reinstalling scapy 2.3.2) How i do it automaticly ? or i have to do it only manualy?

Comment: I don't know how this works under windows, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that after uninstalling and reinstalling scapy I didnt reboot my machine and that made the error!
For people that might get my error about, just remove scapy from your machine and reboot it and install latest scapy version.